# html2canvas not rendering properly for specific data uri

Tags: javascript, reactjs, html2canvas

I have div like this

[image]

after rendering output shows like this.

[image]

html2canvas code:

```
html2canvas(document.getElementById('widgetElemet'), {
    logging: true,
    profile: true,
    useCORS: true,
    allowTaint: true,
    onrendered: function(canvas) {
        var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL();

        var param = {
            to: emailToArray.validEmails,
            cc: emailCCArray.validEmails,
            bcc: emailBccArray.validEmails,
            emailid: UserDetails.email,
            subject: emailSubject,
            message: emailMessage,
            ImageDataURI: dataURL
        }

        this.postScreenShot(param)    
    }.bind(this)
```

})

data uri for that image

```
data:image/svg+xml;base64,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
```

Comment: It looks to me like whatever the html2canvas library is doing, it is not understanding the size of the image, is it an img tag, or background on a div? How is it different to the other ones?

Comment: That must be broken image. Try to open same image in photoshop and see is this corrupt or not.

Comment: @2pha it's img tag having src as data url in all the images.

Comment: @yogendarji image is not broken. You can check by coping data url string on browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just checked your `base64 SVG` and see it shows it shows `width` and `height` `0` so that might be the issue.

Alternative solution is apply same `base64 SVG` as `background-image` to `div` and your issue will be fixed.

```js
window.takeScreenShot = function() {
  html2canvas(document.getElementById("target"), {
    onrendered: function(canvas) {
      document.body.appendChild(canvas);
    },
    width: 300,
    height: 300
  });
}
```

```css
#target {
  background-image: url('data:image/svg+xml;base64,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');
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
}

button {
  display: block;
  height: 20px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/html2canvas/0.4.1/html2canvas.min.js"></script>

<div id="target">
</div>

<button onclick="takeScreenShot()">to image</button>
```

[image]

Comment: @PiyushDhamecha can you put sample fiddle?

Comment: the problem was exactly same you have mentioned.. i just added height and width as parent height and width by decoding svg and again encoded to base64.. Thanks bro..

Answer (score -2):

I was using .png, but the html2canvas can't display the .png file.

So I used svg instead of .png -- convert .png into .svg.

It worked for me.